# VBA to open workbook, copy certain cells into specific sheets, and close source woorkbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I have created a workbook that I send to other employees so they record certain items. The user will save the workbook as "STATS (their badge number)" and send it back. I copy the cells from their books (Sheet1.range("B4:B29") and .Range("F1:G2) and paste into my master workbook (STATS Total) on tabs that are named with each employee's last name. I am trying to automate opening the numerous books they send me (all in the same folder), copy the data, then paste it into the same cells (B4:B29 and F1:G2 on their named sheets, then close the "source" workbooks. To help, I put the full pathname to each "source" book in Cell("I2" on their sheet in the master book. So in the masterbook, there is a sheet named "Smith" and in I2 is the pathname to the workbook he sent me. This is the code I have tried, but I cannot get it to work. What should I be doing different?

```
Sub CopyAndPaste()
Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set x = Workbook(Sheet6.Range("I2").Text) 'copied book
Set y = ThisWorkbook 'pasted to this book


Set ws1 = x.Sheet1 'copied from
Set ws2 = y.Sheets("copied to")

ws1.Cells.Copy ws2.Cells
y.Close True
x.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: specify what does _"I cannot get it to work"_  actually mean (what error, which line throws it, etc...)

Comment: Starting with "Sub or Function Not Defined" on the line "Set x..."

Comment: I'm sorry about that - I know better than to leave that out. It appears to not let me use "Sheet6.Range("I2").Text" to specify the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
Sheet6.Range("I2").value
```

Instead of :

```
Sheet6.Range("I2").text
```

More than that, you need to open the workbook if it's not already opened (and I guess it's not the case if you have to do it for multiple workbooks). So you could have:

```
Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim input_workbook as String

Set y = ActiveWorkbook 'I consider this as the workbook you launch the macro from
input_workbook = Sheet6.Range("I2").value 

'I guess Sheet6 is in workbook y ... 
'in any case, it should represent a folder path with the workbook name, 
'like "C:\Documents\MyExcelFile.xlsx"

Set x = workbooks.open(filename:=input_workbook) 'The input workbook that you need to open

'... rest of the code ...
```

Hope this helps!

**#1 EDIT**

To answer your question, you can now simply use x and y as the workbooks. So you might have:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = y.sheets("your_y_sheet_name")
Set ws2 = x.sheets("your_x_sheet_name")
```

You can then use these variables to transfer data:

```
ws1.range("B1:C10").value = ws2.range("B1:C10").value
```

This will make your range B1:C10 in ws1 (wb y) equal to the one in ws2 (wb x). This is absolutely faster than copy/pasting. So, if you have a fixed range to transfer from x to y, just use this like that (just use the correct ranges; they should have the same size).

Once you are done with you x workbook, do not forget to close it:

```
x.close
```

Comment: Thank you. This code opens the workbook I need opened. But to set what gets copied out of the new book into y (you're right, that's where the macro is launched and is the activeworkbook, how do I call the ne workbook? ```Workbooks(Filename:=input_workbook).Sheet1``` gives error "named argument not found"